# How many weight units does an input use?

Tags: transaction-input

What is the weight unit cost of an input? And can you batch/aggregate the inputs or is it linearly growth when you add more inputs to a tx?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the weight unit cost of an input?

2 things affect the weight of a tx, the total number of bytes , and the total bytes minus witness data.

`Transaction Weight = Base transaction size * 3 + Total transaction size`, where

**Base transaction size** is the size of the transaction serialised with the witness data stripped.

**Total transaction size** is the transaction size in bytes serialized as described in [BIP144](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0144.mediawiki), including base data and witness data.

See [BIP141](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki)

> Can you batch/aggregate the inputs or is it linearly growth when you
>   add more inputs to a tx?

You can't batch inputs, but you can combine them and send them back to yourself first in a larger amount, but that requires an additional transaction. Probably the best you can do now is to use a segwit address to receive funds so when you go to spend the inputs, the witness data lowers the weight of each input.

Comment: And to address OP's specific question, yes, this means that transaction size grows linearly with the number of inputs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am however still wondering how heavy an input is?

Comment: It depends on the scriptSig, see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/68811/what-is-the-absolute-smallest-size-of-the-data-bytes-that-a-blockchain-transac and https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction#General_format_.28inside_a_block.29_of_each_input_of_a_transaction_-_Txin

Answer (score 1):

The weight of a single input in a transaction always uses:

- `32` bytes to reference the outpoint id (hash)
- `4` bytes to reference the outpoint index

Then, if the outpoint is a non-segwit p2pkh output the scriptSig uses:

- `1` byte to denote the scriptSig size
- `1` byte to denote the signature size
- `71` bytes (on average) for the signature
- `1` byte to denote the public key size
- `33` bytes for the public key

In total this makes `143` bytes (on average) to reference a non-segwit p2pkh output with your spending transaction.

For segwit p2sh nested p2pkh outputs, the scriptSig uses instead:

- `1` byte to denote the scriptSig size
- `1` byte to denote the witness version (0x00)
- `1` byte to denote the public key hash size
- `20` bytes for the public key hash

Further, the witnessScript will use the same amount of bytes as the scriptSig for spending non-witness p2pkh outpoints. However, the witnessScript only counts with a quarter to the total weight.

Therefore a segwit p2sh nested input has a weight contribution of `59` bytes + (`107`)/4 bytes = `86` bytes on average.